# Compiler condition for target membership running in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, watchkit

The `#available` compiler check in Swift (introduced in Swift 2.0) doesn't seem to work with Target Membership.

For example, I have different targets in my project that are for iOS, watchOS, tvOS, OS X, etc. Some files are included in more than one target membership. I'm trying to do this:

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
} else if #available(watchOS 1.0, *) {
    locationManager.requestLocation()
}
```

The error in Xcode says: `'startUpdatingLocation()' is unavailable`. However, this file is common to both platforms and targets. Am I approaching this wrong? How can I mix platform code within the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally compile code for each platform, using the `os()` directive:

```
#if os(iOS)
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
#elseif os(watchOS)
    locationManager.requestLocation()
#else
    ...
#endif
```

Valid arguments are `OSX`, `iOS`, `watchOS`, and `tvOS`.

This way, your common code which is used by more than one target will only contain compiled code specific to that build configuration.

For more information, see Build Configurations in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_20).