# Exclude notification methods for tvOS using @available

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, usernotifications

I'm studying [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) framework and have the following method to respond to user's actions on a notification.

```
func userNotificationCenter (_ pNotificationCenter: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive pResponse: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler pCompletionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) -> Void {
    ...
}
```

This works well in iOS and iPadOS, but the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter) says this delegate method is not applicable for tvOS - which leads me to believe that notification banners cannot be displayed in tvOS - which is ok.

But the problem is, how do I make this compile for tvOS? I'm getting the following error

```
error: 'UNNotificationResponse' is unavailable in tvOS
...
error: cannot override 'userNotificationCenter' which has been marked unavailable
```

I tried using the [@available](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/attributes/#available) attribute, which would include this method only for iOS and iPadOS 10.0 and above.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
```

But this doesn't work. I still get the same error. Macros can work, but what's wrong in the way I've used @available?

How do I selectively disable this function for tvOS using @available?

**Update1:** Even if I wrap the empty function as shown below, I still get the same error.

```
#if os(tvOS)
func userNotificationCenter (_ pNotificationCenter: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive pResponse: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler pCompletionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) -> Void {

}    
#endif
```

**Update2**: Silly mistake in update 1. If I need the above code to be available only for iOS and iPadOS, I should have used

```
#if os(iOS)
```

instead of

```
#if os(tvOS)
```

Comment: Did you try to compile conditionally like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462375/compiler-condition-for-target-membership-running-in-swift/35464314#35464314) This should do...

Comment: @WolfgangWilke, I tried `#if os(tvOS)`. Didn't work. Same error. This is similar to macros, right? I thought it would work...

Comment: Did you exclude the function and the references to it compeltly???

Comment: @WolfgangWilke yes. The function doesn't contain any code (exactly as depicted in question). I wrapped the empty function with `#if os(tvOS)` and `#endif`.

Comment: @WolfgangWilke, I have pasted the updated code in the question (under update section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the function if you have os(tvOS) but you want the function declared only if you have it not. In the conditional compilation you have not a direct negation. So a solution would be:

```swift
#if os(tvOS)
    
#warning("Not implemented in tvOS") // or if you want #error(...)    
        
#else
        
func userNotificationCenter (_ pNotificationCenter: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive pResponse: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler pCompletionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) -> Void {
....

}
```

So the function is only declared if you don't have tvOS.

[Here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/using-compiler-directives-in-swift/) you find some more examples on conditional compilation but you find a lot more in the web...

Comment: Thanks. This definitely works. But I was hoping for a solution using @available (as mentioned in question)? Because I want some methods to be available for certain versions of the OS. #if will exclude the entire method for every version of the OS.

Comment: After reading [this post](https://forums.swift.org/t/if-vs-available-vs-if-available/40266) in swift forums about #if, @available and #available, I see that in this case, #if must be used... since any version of tvOS should not see the userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) delegate method. This is the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For disable selectively the feature on tvOS using the property @available,
adding unavailable on tvOS, unavailable to the @available property.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *, unavailableIn: .tvOS)
```

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. This syntax seems to be wrong. I've got syntax errors like `error: expected declaration` and `error:expected version number` in addition to the errors reported in question.